# I am trying to display images from TMDB API but my code doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

Below code is the function for displaying the movie's images with different categories. The browser and vs code doesn't show an error but still, I cannot get the result. help!!

```
  function Row({ title, fetchUrl, isLargeRow = false }) {
          const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
          const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";
        
          useEffect(() => {
            async function fetchData() {
              const request = await axios.get(fetchUrl);
              setMovies(request.data.results);
              return request;
            }
            fetchData();
          }, [fetchUrl]);
        
          //   console.log(movies);
        
          return (
            <div className="row">
              <h2>{title}</h2>
        
              {movies.map((movie) => (
                <img
                  // "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/" + movie.poster_path || movie.backdrop_path
        
                  src={
                    "${base_url}${isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path:movie.backdrop_path}"
                  }
                  alt={movie.name}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          );
        }
        
        export default Row;
```

Here for this code "${base_url}${isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path:movie.backdrop_path}", I tried to replace (") with backtik(') but the vs code replace back on saving.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this : `const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";`
Try this : `const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";`

Please remove forward slash at the end as `poster_path` already has a `/`
`/9PFonBhy4cQy7Jz20NpMygczOkv.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax.
Map all the image elements in one parent component.

```
<div className="row_posters">
  {movies?.map((movie, index) => {
    let moviesDiv = (
      <div key={index} className="row_posters">
        <img src={`${baseURL}${movie.poster_path}`} alt={movie.name} />;
      </div>
    );

    return moviesDiv
  })}
</div>
```